# Python Selenium Error

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Selenium on Python is returning this error message. Would anyone happen to know how to fix?

```
C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/nvarga/PycharmProjects/HWIN/HWIN Account Spending Report.py" Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file) File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in init restore_signals, start_new_session) File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/nvarga/PycharmProjects/HWIN/HWIN Account Spending Report.py", line 127, in HWIN_Spending_Report(ID, Username, Password, 50) File "C:/Users/nvarga/PycharmProjects/HWIN/HWIN Account Spending Report.py", line 13, in HWIN_Spending_Report browser = webdriver.Firefox() File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in init self.service.start() File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception ignored in: > Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in del self.stop() File "C:\Users\nvarga\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop if self.process is None: AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download geckodriver [from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and put the directory it is in into your PATH variable. Either that or pass the path to geckodriver as the `executable_path` argument to `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')`